# conduit stream to list of actions

Tags: haskell, conduit

I have:

- an infinite network stream as source `(responseBody response)`
- a parser: `myParser = many1 parseOneObj` of type `Parser [MyObj]`

I would like to handle each object (for example printing it on screen).

I am stuck here. I tried things like:

```
responseBody response C.$$++ sinkParser myParser
                      C.$$-- CL.mapM_ B.putStrLn
```

Which obviously doesn't even compile. Could someone help me in finding the right way to handle this correctly (and efficiently)? For example, in the end, I would like to have many threads to handle the push of the objects in DB.

For now, I am struggling at Type Tetris, any help will be more than welcome! Thanks!

---

The complete solution for anyone in the future:

```
responseBody response C.$$++ conduitParser parseOneObj 
                      C.=$ CL.mapM_ (liftIO . (B.putStrLn . snd))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I'd recommend: using `many1 parseOneObj` will defeat any possibility of streaming. Instead, I'd use `conduitParser parseOneObj`. Then you probably just need to replace `C.$$--` with `C.=$`.

Comment: Thanks a thousand times Michael. I had found the conduitParser parseOneObj but I couldn't find the =$. I had to add a liftIO thought. Thanks again!